# bypass spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

i have a web service and i want that everybody accesses this service.

in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChainRendering</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
    <filter-mapping>
           <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChainRemoting</filter-name>
           <url-pattern>/cxf/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

in filters-chain-remoting.xml

```
       <bean id="springSecurityFilterChainRemoting" class="org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <!-- Remoting: stateful WebServices; 
            httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter creates SecurityContext 
            and populates it with information obtained from the HttpSession. 
            contextFilter supplies context with 
            the current project for the current HTTP user session; 
            securityFilter authenticates the user. -->

         <security:filter-chain pattern="/cxf/KioskService/**"
            filters="none"/>

        <security:filter-chain pattern="/cxf/**"
            filters="httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter, contextFilter,securityFilter"/>

    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

how can i do that bypass these filters and everybody consume this service. Service name KioskService

Answer (score 1):

Change the web.xml filter mapping definition from:

```
<url-pattern>/cxf/*</url-pattern>
```

to intercept only the urls that you want security on.